# Making scoreboards and other dynamic graphics in DirectShow

Tags: directshow

We're working on a system to stream live sports events from the local high school stadium.  We're feeding three IP streaming cameras into a laptop and switching between them with a DirectShow application we built in Visual Studio.  We would like to superimpose a scoreboard and subtitles identifying the people onscreen but have run up against a problem:  Once the DirectShow filter graph is running, it doesn't allow the file capture filter to reload the file so we can't change the score or subtitles!  We tried making StreamBufferSinks to isolate the file capture modules so we could shut them off to reload the graphics, but could never get that to work...

Are we barking up the wrong tree?  Is there a better way to do this?  If DirectShow is the best solution, what is the best way to superimpose multiple .TGA, PNG or XAML files onto the video being mixed in VMR9 in a way that they can be updated during the game?